# Is there a way to shorten the if else statements with switch?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I need to find a way to shorten my if-else statements with switch. The if-else statements are really long and they look really unprofessional and I hope there is a way to shorten them into a couple of lines instead of the mess of multiple lines as I have it now.

I tried to implement a switch block but it didn't go correctly and the way I wanted it to go.

```
int numbers(int tal[]) {
int choice,a;
printf("\nWrite a specific number: ");
scanf("%d", &choice);
int b = 0;
for(a = 0 ;a < MAX ;a++){
    if(tal[a]== choice){
        b = 1;
        printf("\nExists in the sequence on this location: ");
        if(a <= 9)
        printf(" Row 1 och column %d\n",a +1);
        else if (a > 9 &&a <= 19)
        printf(" Row 2 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 10);
        else if (a > 19 &&a <= 29)
        printf(" Row 3 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 20);
        else if (a > 29 &&a <= 39)
        printf(" Row 4 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 30);
        else if (a > 39 &&a <= 49)
        printf(" Row 5 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 40);
        else if (a > 49 &&a <= 59)
        printf(" Row 6 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 50);
        else if (a > 59 &&a <= 69)
        printf(" Row 7 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 60);
        else if (a > 69 &&a <= 79)
        printf(" Row 8 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 70);
        else if (a > 79 &&a <= 89)
        printf(" Row 9 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 80);
        else if (a > 89 &&a <= 99)
        printf(" Row 10 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 90);
        break;
    }
}
if (b == 0)
    printf("\n%d It does not exists in the sequence", choice);
}
```

I got it working, and I changed all the if-else statements to this one;
edit: nvm the column answer I get is incorrect.

```
int choice,a,row,col;
printf("\nWrite a specific number: ");
scanf("%d", &choice);
int b = 0;
for(a = 0 ;a < MAX ;a++){
    if(tal[a]== choice){
        b = 1;
        printf("\nExists in the sequence on this location: ");
        if(a <= 9)
       col = a % 10 + 1;
       row = a / 10 + 1;
       printf("Row %d och column %d\n", row, col);
        break;
    }
}
if (b == 0)
    printf("\n%d It does not exists in the sequence", choice);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO4nz.png)

Comment: There is a way to shorten this but not with `switch`, but by noticing few things. For example that the first condition in each `else if` is redundant. But this whole conditional is not needed at all if you see the pattern and use a single `printf` line with  *a bit* more complicated arithmetic expression.

Comment: Please don't invalidate existing answers by removing necessary information from the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make it look a bit better by:

- Properly indenting it
- Omitting redundant checks with `>`

like that:

```
if(a <= 9)
    printf(" Row 1 och column %d\n",a +1);
else if (a <= 19)
    printf(" Row 2 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 10);
else if (a <= 29)
    printf(" Row 3 och column %d\n", (a +1) - 20);
...
```

But in this case you can completely avoid the if-block by calculating the values, for example like that:

```
col = a % 10 + 1;
row = a / 10 + 1;

print("Row %d och column %d\n", row, col);
```

Comment: @maker Where does the column calculation differ compared to your original solution?

Comment: If I select a number that is in the last row and last column, the answer I should get is that the number is located in the 10th column and 10th row, but I get the answer that it is located in the 10th row and 0th column.

Comment: @maker `a%10+1` can _never_ be 0 for a>0

Comment: check the image link, you'll see my console-based program, and you can clearly see that it writes out that the last number is located in the column 0.

Comment: Drop the `if (a <= 9)` , who suggested that?!

Comment: thanks for the answer, it fixed my issue with the columns. I still have an issue with my swift and case parts of it, if you have any idea how to make it better then check out my post about it.